# What is this yellow hinge piece named?

Tags: part-identification

Recently, I've been flipping through a scan of the March 1995 edition of the LEGO Mania Magazine. Something in the corner of page 11 caught my eye:

[image]

This is the 5th step of the "Flip & Build" segment. I am absolutely puzzled; what is that yellow element that forms that arm? (And by extension, how does it clip to that 1x2 black plate?)

Bear in mind that this is from 1995, so it's no surprise if this piece is discontinued now despite being common back then. Really, what piece is that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think this is the yellow element: **Hinge Bar 2 with 3 Fingers and Top Stud**

[image: Hinge Bar 2 with 3 Fingers and Top Stud]

And this the black "plate": **Hinge Plate 1 x 2 with 2 Fingers and Solid Studs**

[image: Hinge Plate 1 x 2 with 2 Fingers and Solid Studs]

Both elements are hinges, so they can connect.

Comment: That's definitely it - funny how the black parts look more grey than black, though, but that's 1995 for you

Comment: The black parts still look more grey than black in the printed instructions!

Comment: all the parts in the instructions are outlined in black, so the inside of the black parts are colored a little bit lighter. this way you can see details like open or solid studs

Comment: Yes, I believe that is it. Uncommon part, but still available in the current LDD lineup.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this piece is also used as a fork and fits in the hand of minifigures, and the forked end can also fit into the slits of a 1x2 grill piece.